# git grep <regex containing newline>

Tags: regex, git, git-grep

I'm trying to grep all [line breaks after some binary operators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#should-a-line-break-before-or-after-a-binary-operator) in a project using git bash on a Windows machine.

Tried the following commands which did not work:

```
$ git grep "[+-*\|%]\ *\n"
fatal: command line, '[+-*\|%]\ *\n': Invalid range end

$ git grep "[+\-*\|%]\ *\n"
fatal: command line, '[+\-*\|%]\ *\n': Invalid range end
```

OK, I don't know how to include "-" in a character set, but still after removing it the `\n` matches the character `n` literally:

```
$ git grep "[+*%] *\n"
somefile.py:            self[:] = '|' + name + '='
                                      ^^^
```

Escaping the backslash once (`\\n`) has no effect, and escaping it twice (`\\\n`) causes the regex to match `\n` (literally).

What is the correct way to grep here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't know how to include "-" in a character set

There is no need to escape the dash character (`-`) if you want to include it in a character set. If you put it the first or the last character in set it doesn't have its special meaning.

Also, there is no need to escape `|` inside a character range. Apart from `^` (when it's the first character in the range), `-` (when it is not the first or the last character in the range), `]` and `\` (when it is used to escape `]`), all other characters have their literal meaning (i.e no special meaning) in a character range.

There is also no need to put `\n` in the regexp. The grepping tools, by default, try to match the regexp against one row at a time and `git grep` does the same. If you need to match the regexp only at the end of line then put `$` (the end of line anchor) as the last character of the regexp.

Your regexp should be `[-+*|%] *$`.

Put together, the complete command line is:

```
git grep '[-+*|%] *$'
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to use `grep '[-+*|%]\s*$'` to account for windows line endings. It turns out that I could also find the answer in [grep manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions). See also: [Is it better to use git grep than plain grep if we want to search in versioned source code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557684/is-it-better-to-use-git-grep-than-plain-grep-if-we-want-to-search-in-versioned-s)

Answer (score 0):

**How to find a newline in the middle of a line**

For lack of better option I think I'll start with:

```
sudo apt install pcregrep
git grep --cached -Il '' | xargs pcregrep -Mb 'y\nl'
```

this combines:

- [How to list all text (non-binary) files in a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973057/how-to-list-all-text-non-binary-files-in-a-git-repository/24350112#24350112)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112132/how-can-i-grep-patterns-across-multiple-lines/112134#112134

The output clearly shows the filename and line number, e.g.:

```
myfile.txt:123:my
love
myfile.txt:234:my
life
otherfile.txt:11:my
lion
```

Tested on Ubuntu 22.04.